# Alternatives to Msgbox  in VBScript

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, active-directory, login-script

I want to show status information after a VBS based login script runs.  I could simply use a Messagebox, but would rather have this information appear above the clock briefly after the user logs in.

What alternatives do I have instead of a Messagebox?

Comment: You can call PowerShell from VBScript. That might actually be the simplest work-around. In my opinion, VBScript really isn't suitable to be used where any amount of user interface is needed (unless you're using it to program webpages in ASP, but even then it's no good for host-side GUI).

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is something like a balloon tip.  There is nothing like this available in VBScript natively.  You would need to use a third-party component.

As an aside, PowerShell IS able to do this.

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"Reboot Required","Please restart your computer",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

Comment: Outside of using VS2010, how would I compile this?  Using csc?

Comment: @makerofthings7: powershell is an interpreted language, and is included in Windows 7/2008R2 and downloadable for XP/Vista/2003/2008.  Start with http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you can go pure powershell I highly recommend this snippet works great!

**Example**

[image]

**Code**

```
##################
# Messenger like popup dialog
# Usage:
# New-Popup.ps1
# New-Popup.ps1 -slide -message "hello world" -title "PowerShell Popup"


param(
    [int]$formWidth=200, 
    [int]$formHeight=110,
    [string]$title="Your title here",
    [string]$message="Your message here",
    [int]$wait=4,
    [switch]$slide
)

[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

################
# extract powershell icon if doesn't exist
$icon = "$env:temp\posh.ico"
if( !(test-path -pathType leaf $icon)){
    [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((get-process -id $pid).path).ToBitmap().Save($icon)
}

################
# Create the form
$form = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize = new-object System.Drawing.Size($formWidth,$formHeight)
$form.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::LightBlue
$form.ControlBox = $false
$form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.topMost=$true

# initial form position
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::Manual

if($slide){
    $top = $screen.WorkingArea.height + $form.height
    $left = $screen.WorkingArea.width - $form.width
    $form.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point($left,$top)
} else {
    $top = $screen.WorkingArea.height - $form.height
    $left = $screen.WorkingArea.width - $form.width
    $form.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point($left,$top)
}

################
# pictureBox for icon 
$pictureBox = new-object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox 
$pictureBox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(2,2)
$pictureBox.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)
$pictureBox.TabStop = $false
$pictureBox.SizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage
$pictureBox.Load($icon)


################
# create textbox to display the  message
$textbox = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textbox.Text = $message
$textbox.BackColor = $form.BackColor
$textbox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(4,26)
$textbox.Multiline = $true
$textbox.TabStop = $false
$textbox.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::None
$textbox.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(192,77)
$textbox.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default
$textbox.HideSelection = $false


################
# Create 'Close' button, when clicked hide and dispose the form
$button = new-object system.windows.forms.button 
$button.Font = new-object System.Drawing.Font("Webdings",5)
$button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(182,3)
$button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(16,16)
$button.Text = [char]114
$button.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$button.Add_Click({ $form.hide(); $form.dispose() })
if($slide) {$button.visible=$false}


################
# Create a label, for title text
$label = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Font = new-object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft
$label.Text = $title
$label.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(24,3)
$label.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(174, 20)


################
# Create a timer to slide the form
$timer = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Enabled=$false
$timer.Interval=10
$timer.tag="up"
$timer.add_tick({

    if(!$slide){return}

    if($timer.tag -eq "up"){
        $timer.enabled=$true
        $form.top-=2
        if($form.top -le ($screen.WorkingArea.height - $form.height)){
            #$timer.enabled=$false
            $timer.tag="down"
            start-sleep $wait
        }
    } else {

        $form.top+=2
        if($form.top -eq ($screen.WorkingArea.height + $form.height)){
            $timer.enabled=$false
            $form.dispose()
        }
    }
})


# add form event handlers
$form.add_shown({
    $form.Activate()
    (new-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer "$env:windir\Media\notify.wav").play()
    $timer.enabled=$true
})

# draw seperator line 
$form.add_paint({    
    $gfx = $form.CreateGraphics()        
    $pen = new-object System.Drawing.Pen([System.Drawing.Color]::Black)
    $gfx.drawLine($pen,0,24,$form.width,24)      
    $pen.dispose()
    $gfx.dispose()
})



################
# add controls to the form
# hide close button if form is not sliding

if($slide){
    $form.Controls.AddRange(@($label,$textbox,$pictureBox))
} else {
    $form.Controls.AddRange(@($button,$label,$textbox,$pictureBox))
}

################
# show the form
[void]$form.showdialog()
```

save as New-Popup.ps1 to keep the usage the same. Kudo's to the author of http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2008/02/windows-messenger-like-popup.html

Comment: Looks quite cool.  I'll have to figure out how to cancel the sound and make it fade in / out (not requiring a click)

Comment: Whats great is you can copy this ps1 out to a place on the HD and send out messages at any time with psexec and a list of your computer names

Comment: There should be a way to use WinRM / Powershell tools native to do that remoting with proxy commandlets.  Do you know how to do this?  (Exchange 2010 does this as an example)

Comment: Invoke-Command should do the trick as well i just failed making it work last time i tried, do i answer your question?