# Call a ps1 script with parameters from a VBS script

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, login-script

All my users are using a VBS-based login script.  At the end of the script, [I want to call a PS1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304338/328397) with parameters that change the contents of the informational balloon.

How should VBS call a PS1 with parameters?

Comment: powershell something.ps1 -var1 -var2 not working?

Comment: I have an all powershell version of a pop up box if you like as well.. let me know.

Comment: @dc5553 That would be great, can you post on the linked thread?  Also, I'm new to VBS calling PS1 so I'm not sure where to begin.  PS1 has all these signing restrictions and is picky about so many things I'm not sure where to begin

Comment: there you go, i hope you like it, trying to find the author now so he gets credit fo rit, a wonderful little snippet

Comment: Will this help - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/ilm2/thread/65334d6c-6902-4541-89ce-ffe90b2208d0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey Snover has the answer it seems - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/07/25/invoking-powershell-from-vbscript-com.aspx

Excerpt from the blog -

With ActiveXPosh you can do things like:

```
Set ActiveXPosh = CreateObject("SAPIEN.ActiveXPosh")
if ActiveXPosh.Eval("Get-Process Winword") = vbTrue Then
     WScript.Echo "Word is running"
Else
     WScript.Echo "Word is NOT running"
End If
```

Pretty simple stuff!  So - how could it get any better?  Yup - you guessed it, **ActiveXPosh is FREE.**  Is this a wonderful world or what?

NOTE- I have not tried though.