# Word VBA: Static Status dialog window

Tags: vba, ms-word, dialog, msgbox

I've created a form that works well with macros running in the background to validate data and then print the document to a specific printer on the network.

The key element of this process is a production number value which I would like to keep a running log of and display in a static status dialog window.  In other words, a popup window similar to a MsgBox that would not interfere with other actions on the form, but float on top of the document.

Visual concept of this would be...

[image]

User could shift the window away from their work if needed. Close the window if they desired, but pragmatically I want to re-pop/refresh the data in the window each time the background macro completes.

I can't use MsgBox, because it forces a closure of the window before the user can continue working on the document. I just want this visible to the user so they know what was last worked on and the few prior to that.

Any idea what control I might be able to use, or switch to MsgBox that would allow the user to continue working?

Ken...

PS: I found this and am trying to find a way to make this work for me. So far I have managed to get to function in the manner I want, but the lingering issue is how to call this PS script and include the information I need to display.
[Alternatives to MsgBox in VBScript - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302421/alternatives-to-msgbox-in-vbscript)

PPS: I opted to go a slightly different route and release the form with a MsgBox that is displayed at the end of the macro. I describe this in the solution noted below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing much research, I've come back to revising my macro to incorporate static variables and a MsgBox at the end to report the last 5 production numbers that have been printed.

To provide a means of bringing up this MsgBox for reference, between printing runs, I created an OnlyNum variable as string and replaced the MsgBox I had for letting the users know they were only to use numbers in this field with that message. The end of that trap diverted the flow to the bottom of the macro (where the MsgBox that displayed the last five print jobs has been placed).

So, when the status MsgBox is displayed as a result of printing it only shows the last five events. If the trap captures it, it shows the message letting the user know to only use numerals and then displays the last five events.

Code reference:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Prod As String
Dim Temp As String
Dim OnlyNum As String

Static ProdNum1 As String
Static ProdNum2 As String
Static ProdNum3 As String
Static ProdNum4 As String
Static ProdNum5 As String

'Check for only numeric value of TextBox1.Text
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
    OnlyNum = "only numbers allowed" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Cancel = True
    GoTo NotToday
End If

'Remove any spaces from TextBox1.Text 
Prod = Replace(TextBox1.Text, " ", "")

'If the resulting lenght is equal to 7 Print it.
    If Len(Prod) = 7 Then
        ActiveDocument.PrintOut

'Update recent production numbers (5 in total)      
    ProdNum5 = ProdNum4
    ProdNum4 = ProdNum3
    ProdNum3 = ProdNum2
    ProdNum2 = ProdNum1

    ProdNum1 = Prod & " - " & Now()  ' Insert a new production number with timestamp

    TextBox1.Text = ""    'Clear the value of TextBox1.Text to prepare for the next Production number

  Else
    MsgBox ("Production Numbers must be 7 digits and contain only numerials.")
End If

NotToday:
    Application.ActivePrinter = Temp
    MsgBox (OnlyNum & ProdNum1 & vbCrLf & ProdNum2 & vbCrLf & ProdNum3 & vbCrLf & ProdNum4 & vbCrLf & ProdNum5)
    OnlyNum = ""  'Reset value of OnlyNum 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a MsgBox, please consider using a VBA Userform. They're not much more complicated to use than a MegBox, but you can set them to be **Modeless**. Modeless dialogs remain open on-screen while you work on the Word document. Here'is Microsoft's page on setting dialogs as Modal or Modeless: [Show method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method)

If you search on *VBA modeless dialog*, you'll find many other helpful pages on the subject.